# I am not able to store the returned value of a javaScript function (of Geocoding) in a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, geocode

I am trying to store the latitude and longitude values I calculated inside the function. If I `console.log` both the values inside the function, it is working fine. However, if I return those values to use them somewhere else, then I cannot do so *(it throws an error in the console as having this* `coordinates` *list as undefined)*. Whatever I am returning from this `Geocoding` function, it shows undefined in the console. Here is the code snippet:

```
function Geocoding() {
  axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
    params: {
      address: enteredAddress,
      key: 'my API key here'
    }
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      var lat = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
      var lng = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
      return [lat, lng];
    })

    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}

const submitHandler = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  var coordinates = Geocoding();

  const userInput = { //object
    location: {
      latitude: coordinates[0],
      longitude: coordinates[1],
      maxDistance: enteredDistance
    },
    instrumentType: enteredInstrumentType,
    awardNumber: enteredAwardNumber,
    includeRetired: enteredIRI
  };
  props.onSaveUserInput(userInput);

  setEnteredAddress('');
  setEnteredDistance('');
  setEnteredInstrumentType('');
  setEnteredAwardNumber('');
  setEnteredIRI('');
};
```

Comment: The request to get the coordinates data is not completing fast enough for the submitHandler method to use. You need to call the submitHandler method from within your then() block so the data is available for the method to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `Geocoding` is not returning anything. Anyway, I'd convert the code to `async`/`await` if possible so it's easier to comprehend. Take a look below at the same code fixed with `async`/`await`.

```js
async function Geocoding() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
      params: {
        address: enteredAddress,
        key: 'my API key here'
      }
    })
    
    var lat = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    var lng = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    return [lat, lng];
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    throw error;
  }
}

const submitHandler = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  var coordinates = await Geocoding();

  const userInput = { //object
    location: {
      latitude: coordinates[0],
      longitude: coordinates[1],
      maxDistance: enteredDistance
    },
    instrumentType: enteredInstrumentType,
    awardNumber: enteredAwardNumber,
    includeRetired: enteredIRI
  };
  props.onSaveUserInput(userInput);

  setEnteredAddress('');
  setEnteredDistance('');
  setEnteredInstrumentType('');
  setEnteredAwardNumber('');
  setEnteredIRI('');
};
```

Notice that to call `Geocoding` you need to use also `async`/`await` or use the `Promise.then` like `Geocoding().then((coordinates) => {...})`

Answer (score 1):

Your Geocoding does not return variables. It just calls another function.

```
function Geocoding() {
    axios.get().then().catch();
}
```

The `get`/`then`/`catch` functions return a `Promise`. You can return the `Promise`.

```
function Geocoding() {
    return axios.get().then().catch();
}
```

You can get the variable by calling `then`.

```
const submitHandler = event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  Geocoding().then(coordinates => {
    const userInput = {
    // ...
    setEnteredIRI("");
  });
};
```

By the way, if there is an error, you catch it in the `Geocoding` function, and return nothing in the `catch`. The `coordinates` in `Geocoding().then(coordinates => {})` will be undefined.

You can change it:

```
function Geocoding() {
  return axios
    .get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json", {
      params: {
        address: enteredAddress,
        key: "my API key here",
      },
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      var lat = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
      var lng = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
      return [lat, lng];
    });
}

const submitHandler = event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  Geocoding()
    .then(coordinates => {
      const userInput = {
        //object
        location: {
          latitude: coordinates[0],
          longitude: coordinates[1],
          maxDistance: enteredDistance,
        },
        instrumentType: enteredInstrumentType,
        awardNumber: enteredAwardNumber,
        includeRetired: enteredIRI,
      };
      props.onSaveUserInput(userInput);

      setEnteredAddress("");
      setEnteredDistance("");
      setEnteredInstrumentType("");
      setEnteredAwardNumber("");
      setEnteredIRI("");
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

If you like async/await

```
async function Geocoding() {
  const response = await axios.get(
    "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json",
    {
      params: {
        address: enteredAddress,
        key: "my API key here",
      },
    }
  );
  const lat = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
  const lng = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
  // or
  // const { lat, lng } = response.data.results[0].geometry.location;
  return [lat, lng];
}

const submitHandler = async event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  try {
    const coordinates = await Geocoding();
    const userInput = {
      //object
      location: {
        latitude: coordinates[0],
        longitude: coordinates[1],
        maxDistance: enteredDistance,
      },
      instrumentType: enteredInstrumentType,
      awardNumber: enteredAwardNumber,
      includeRetired: enteredIRI,
    };
    props.onSaveUserInput(userInput);

    setEnteredAddress("");
    setEnteredDistance("");
    setEnteredInstrumentType("");
    setEnteredAwardNumber("");
    setEnteredIRI("");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```